# conditional expectation value of poisson process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-process

I consider a poisson process with rate $$\lambda$$ . Since the Inter arrival time follows exponential distribution, the expectation value of the inter arrival time, say $$E[X]= \frac{1}{\lambda}$$. If I look particularly for a time interval [0-15s]. Then,

1. What would be the expectation value of the inter arrival time e.g.,
   first, second, third arrivals,......? Would it be $$E[X| t<15]$$
2. What is the expectation value of the inter arrival time if I can it
       is conditioned over [5s-15s] i.e., $$E[X| 5<t<15]$$?

Comment: To be clear: Are you looking for $\mathsf E(X\mid X\in[s;t))$ ?  That is the (conditional) expected inter-arrival time when given that it occurs within a specified interval $s\leqslant X<t$.

Comment: By the way, the time until the $k$-th arrival where $k>1$ is not distributed the same as the first arrival.

Comment: Dear @LoveTooNap29 your comment is very right. Would you please elaborate then the right distribution for the $k^{th}$ arrival where $k>1$? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Hallian1990 for $k=1,2,...$ the time until the $k$-th arrival of a Poisson process with mean parameter $\lambda$ is Erlang distributed with parameters $k$ and $\lambda$. The mean time for the $k$-th arrival is $k/\lambda$. Note, an Erlang RV is just a gamma RV with an integer shape parameter, also note when $k=1$, the Erlang distribution reduces to the exponential distribution. If you are unfamiliar with this distribution, a quick google or wiki search will remedy that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the expected inter arrival time when given that that the next event occurs within a particular interval?

$$\begin{align*}\mathsf E(X\mid s\leqslant X\lt t) ~&=~ \dfrac{\int_s^t \lambda x \mathrm e^{-\lambda x}\operatorname d x}{\int_s^t \lambda \mathrm e^{-\lambda x}\operatorname d x} \\[2ex] &=~ \dfrac{(\lambda s+1) \mathrm e^{-\lambda s}-(\lambda t+1)\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}}{\lambda (\mathrm e^{-\lambda s}-\mathrm e^{-\lambda t})}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Hi Kemp. Yes, I am looking to find the conditional expectation value of inter arrival time. I understood your point. Many thanks. I have just a short question to make it clear. for a Poisson process with an time interval e.g., [0-t] and rate lambda, if the first arrival has an expectation value of E[X1]=E[X | 0<=X<t], then for the second arrival can I say the expectation of the second is E[2]= E [X |   E[X1]<=X<t ], means that the second will have expected value between E[X1] and t?

Comment: Dear Kemp, I want to calculate the expected value of the inter arrival time of the FIRST and SECOND arrivals, by considering a poisson process with rate $\lambda$ and for time $t= [0-10s]$ How to express this conditional expectation value. In other words, how much time (expected) will be elapsed until we get 2 arrivals, conditioning time this time is less than $10s$